# Reset (specific) Ubuntu 20.04 color

Tags: gnome, themes

After I installed for testing KDE plasma environment and uninstalled it, a specific portion of some applications is white and just don't get back to the dark it used to be... See images from Calculator and Sunflower. I already tried:

- reinstall ubuntu-desktop (`apt install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop`)
- changing the theme with Gnome Tweaks (any other dark theme has the same issue)
- downloading and applying new dark theme from Gnome Looks

None made it back to the dark it was :(

Does anyone has any holy advice?

[image: Calculator]

[image: Sunflower]

Comment: FYI: When you install a desktop (eg. `kubuntu-desktop`) it also pulls in some themes, wallpapers & can cause some changes to configs, that will survive removal or even purge (eg. `plymouth` wallpaper I see most commonly). In your case it was possibly tweaks you made in KDE Settings that changed the configuration of GTK apps; which is not a *kubuntu* leftover, but likely a user-config change you made in your testing. I use multiple DEs, and always return visual tweaks back prior to removal of DE as it's often easier with the tool used to make initial change (possibly KDE Settings in your case)

Comment: So, if I understood, a *possible* workaround would be to reinstall KDE-plasma and try to tweak the theme from there and see if this white problem gets fixed?

Comment: That isn't required; it's just how I do it as I find it easier. I'm sorry I don't know what setting you're talking about (I don't play much with themes) but it'll be possible without re-installing packages; I just don't know how.You asked for advice; I gave my 2c (it was a FYI as I can't help; information only for next time was my intention)

Comment: Yes, I asked for advice. And I appreciate yours :) I was just trying to understand and perhaps solve this issue :p